# Relationship between two tables in Eloquent (Laravel) based on a secondary table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Maybe I don't know the terminology for this, but I'm trying to create a HasMany relationship between Person and Car object.

```
Person:
id | user_name | created_at ....


Car:
id | make | model | year ...

Person_Car: 
car_id | person_id
```

So obivously the relationship is defined by linking through the Person_Car relationship. Maybe I'm brain farting but I've forgotten what that this relationship is called and how to define `Person` as `hasMany` `Car`s

What's the name of the relationship and how can I define it in a Laravel Eloquent object?

Answer (score 0):

Car class:

```
public function persons()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class);
}
```

Person class:

```
public function cars()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Cars::class);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: How would laravel know to use the person_car table?

Comment: It won't.  By default Laravel will look for it in alphabetical order, so it would expect you to name your table "car_person".  You can easily change this using the second parameter however.

Answer (score 0):

Use many to many relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Car.php

```
public function persons()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Car', 'Person_Car');
}
```